# How do I start a text from a certain distance from the right margin in the same line?

Tags: spacing, margins, indentation, line

I'm trying to put together the title page for my thesis and the university has the instruction to have basically two columns of text at the bottom of the title page. Left column has to have a 4cm margin from the left hand side of the page, the right column has to START at 9cm from the RIGHT side of the page (still in the same line, like in the attached pic. How on earth can I do this? It has to be 9cm from the right side otherwise they can reject my thesis (if they ever check of course).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I would start by setting what's in each column as a separate minipage, and then setting the two minipages side by side.  Specifying the option `[t]` for each minipage should place the top lines at the same baseline.

Comment: First, use geometry to set up the normal margins.  If the left margin is 4cm, great (just remember to `\noindent`).  Otherwise it might get complicated.  You might consider doing the entire title page using tikz [overlay, remember picture].

Comment: I would do it like described by Barbara. But if you really have to use absolute positions for elements, you could also use packages like `textpos`.

Comment: You could also use a tabular with two columns.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz -- I didn't use tabular because one of the elements in the right-hand group can be extended text, and I'd rather allow TeX to decide the break.  Best to use `\raggedright` in that case.